# How do I properly call the other methods in the main method

Tags: java

I am having trouble calling the methods on the main method. This is what I need to have in the main method:

Print the banner message

Get the product ArrayList

Get the product order from the user and check it exists in the product

ArrayList

If the product exists

Get the product price

Compute the product tax

Compute the total sale

Output the total sale

Else

Output "Product not found."

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unit6ProblemSet {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    bannerPrinter();
    ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder();
    Boolean productExists = getOrder(products);
    if(productExists) {
        double price = getPrice();
        getTax(tax);
        getTotal(saleTotal);
        printTotal(saleTotal);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Product not found.");
    }    
}

public static void bannerPrinter() {

    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("****** Welcome to my eCommerce app! ******");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println();
}

public static ArrayList<String> productBuilder() {

    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();

    products.add("Headphones");
    products.add("Pencils");
    products.add("Pens");
    products.add("Computers");
    products.add("Videogames");

    return products;
}

public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userStr = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a product: ");
    userStr = scnr.nextLine();

    boolean productName = products.contains(userStr);

    if (productName) {
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }

    return productName;
}

public static double getPrice() {

    double price = 0.0;
    price = (Math.random() + 1) * 100;

    return price;
}

public static double getTax(double price) {

    double tax = 0.0;
    tax = price * 0.10;

    return tax;
}

public static double getTotal(double price, double tax) {

    double saleTotal = 0.0;
    saleTotal = price + tax;

   return saleTotal;
}

public static void printTotal(double saleTotal) {

    System.out.println("Your sale total is: " + saleTotal);
}

}
```

I am just having trouble calling the different methods in main.

Comment: Which sort of trouble? Please, post the error you observe.

Comment: I am not necessarily having an error, I am just confused on how to call the different methods in the main method. So more along the lines of, I'm not quite sure of how to do it from this point on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path.

```
bannerPrinter();
ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder();
```

The first line in your main method, `bannerPrinter()` calls your `bannerPrinter` method.

Now for your second call for `productBuilder()` you are basically getting a result back. Now using that result you can see if that product exists, get the product prices etc.

So in sort if you want to call a method from main all you have to do is use the method name to make that call.

For methods that have arguments like `getOrder(ArrayList<String> products)` you have to pass an argument to the method.

In your example it would be `getOrder(products)`. that would call the method with the right argument and get a `boolean` result.

Also based on your recent edit when you call a method that has a return type, for example `getOrder()` you need to have a variable that get the result.

`productBuilder()` return a `List<String>` so you did this

`ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder();` Which basically says, get my products and store them in my array list of `products` so I can use it.

Your other getters are doing something similar. You need to store the result and then use that to call your other methods.

I suggest you do some reading on Java in general, since this is a basic question. If this is a Java 101 type of class assignment re-read the first code chapters to get a better understanding of how methods and classes call each other.

Comment: Okay, I was able to write the 'getOrder()' and 'getPrice()' method. However, I am now confused on the last three method calls. I wrote 'getTax(tax)', 'getTotal(saleTotal)', and 'printTotal(saleTotal)'. However in each of those calls, it says it cannot find the symbol?

Comment: Can you update your original post with your changes?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps. I did not give you all the answer outright so you can learn.

Comment: If it helped you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark. Here is how that works: [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a possible issue in your `getOrder` method

```
    public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userStr = "";


        System.out.println("Enter a product: ");
        userStr = scnr.nextLine();

        //Move this after scanning user input
        boolean productName = products.contains(userStr); 

        if (productName) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }

        return productName;
    }
```

In your main method, you keep calling the methods you need by passing the arguments they need and save their return result in a variable

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        bannerPrinter();
        ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder();
        Boolean productExists= getOrder(products); //getOrder needs arraylist and return boolean

        //then check if the returned result is true i.e if product exists
        if(productExists){
        double price = getPrice();

         //do other stuff, calcualte tax on price and then get total and etx
        }
        else{
        //Print "product not found"
        }


    }
```

Comment: Oh good catch on the boolean mistake! Now I am just confused on how to call the other methods

Comment: Your answer also helped; however, I can't accept two answers. But I wanted to thank you very much for helping me with the problem!!